# How to make Gradient Boosting Regression *more* sensitive to outliers?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, boosting

So, I know this is sort of backwards from the normal qustion.  Mostly people want to remove outliers in order to improve their models.  However, the purpose of my model is to find peaks in a predicted signal - which are by definition "outliers" from the rest of the signal.  I find a GBR model can very accurately reproduce my signal everywhere *but* the peaks.

Is there a way to make it more sensitive to the outliers?  Is it just a question of boosting the number of estimators?   I'm wary of overfitting if I increase that too much, not to mention time to fit.

I'm using `sklearn`'s `GradientBoostingRegressor` class if that's helpful.

Comment: How being more sensitive to outliers would help with finding the peaks?

Comment: I figured they would be outliers, since they are by definition not the normal states for the signal.  Am I doing something dumb?  I'm sort of new at this.

Comment: If your model would be *sensitive* to outliers, then this means that the results produced by the model would change (=be incorrect) because of the influence of the outliers. So I don't see how this would help you with detecting anything.

Comment: May be better with anomaly detection.

Comment: Consider breaking the original modelling task in two. One if where we will be predicting if an instance is an outlier and one what an inlier instance's value is. For example it is hard to predict what a VIP client will spend. The error might be larger than the average expenditure of a normal client. It does not make sense to use the same model for both customer instances.